# how to make python 3 itertools product/combinations/permutations from string

Tags: python, python-itertools

> Hi!
>   I want to make mixing strings program in python 3.4. Something like input: string1 = 123, string2 = abc, string3 = 4g6. Output should be like combine of string1, 2 and 3. Example: 1234g6abc. I tried searching in itertools and there was only combine of letters not words. And i want words. Please help.">

Comment: why dont you just concatenate the strings

Answer (score 0):

Add your strings to a list, use [itertools permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), and then join the result.

```
import itertools

L = [string1, string2, string3]
# Convert perms to list if you want to iterate multiple times
perms = itertools.permutations(L)
for perm in perms:
    print(''.join(perm))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools as it

>>> list(map(''.join,list(it.permutations(['234','g6','abc']))))

['234g6abc', '234abcg6', 'g6234abc', 'g6abc234', 'abc234g6', 'abcg6234']
```